# How is client side authentication implemented in MEAN.JS?

Tags: angularjs

Can someone tell how is authentication actually working in MEAN.JS [meanjs.org] here?
When the user logs in,where is the USER json object stored. The code is

```
// Authentication service for user variables
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [
function() {
    var _this = this;

    _this._data = {
        user: window.user
    };

    return _this._data;
}
]);

//The implementation of the service in the controller
     $scope.authentication=Authentication;
// If successful we assign the response to the global user model
     $scope.authentication.user = response;
```

but in console window.user returns null

Another question, how the app retains the user JSON object when the page is refreshed? After the page is refreshed window.user returns the user JSON object, I don't see this object in the Local Storage or Session Storage, neither do i see any ajax being made to the server to fetch this object.

Thanks

Comment: do you want this auth for routing and role managment ?

Comment: Yes I need this for controlling views.